# Why can't I curl and play a .wav file into my Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, curl, jupyter, wav

This is for a Microsoft tutorial that I am attempting to modify, running in a Jupyter notebook.  The example code imports a .wav file and plays it.

If I change the URL in that code to import a different .wav file, it should import and play that .wav file instead.  However, the notebook will not import the new wav and will not play it.

The two .wav files have the same sample rate, so it's not that.  I have tried doing this with Dropbox and Google Drive links as well, no luck.  I even tried downloading the example .wav file, uploading to my own GitHub, and then curling it into the script, and it still did not work.

This code (from the example) works just fine:

```
    import IPython

    !curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MicrosoftLearning/AI-Introduction/master/files/LightOn.wav -o LightOn.wav

    IPython.display.Audio('LightOn.wav', autoplay=True)
```

But when I try to curl from another .wav file, I get a greyed-out player button (the file does not play).

```
    import IPython

    !curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Tylersuard/Tutorial--Home-Automation-With-Azure-and-David-Hasselhoff/blob/master/HandsomeMan.wav -o HandsomeMan.wav

    IPython.display.Audio('HandsomeMan.wav', autoplay=True)
```

Expected result: HandsomeMan.wav imports into Jupyter and then plays.

Actual result: a greyed-out mini player appears, HandsomeMan.wav does not play, and the play button is un-clickable.  The file also appears to have a length of 0:00.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I found the answer.  The problem was not with the audio file itself, it's that for some reason, GitHub was not hosting audio files.  So, I just hosted the file with another service (Vocaroo) and then just got the direct link to the audio file.  If you don't know how to do that, download the audio file, and then in the downloads section of your browser, hover or right-click to find the exact file name, which should end with the file extension.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously there's an issue with the file you're receiving. `curl`'s output says it's just 15 bytes, too small to be a playable audio file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Josh.  But I also downloaded the exact file used in the example, uploaded it to my Git repository, and tried to curl it into my project, and that didn’t work either